# extract text from webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to extract data from website.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

    NSLog(@"finish loading");
 NSLog(@"TEXT of website \n %@",[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText;"]);
NSString *webTextString =  [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innertext;"];
NSLog(@"Website Text:  %@",webTextString);

}
```

NSLog is actually display data but when I copy data to NSString it always stay empty;

Here is response output:
2014-02-04 17:41:07.795 MYAPP[76113:70b] TEXT of website

...... // some more text

ouncils are warning that parts of Britain's road network could become so unsafe the they will need to be shut completely.

Local authorities in some areas say finances are so squeezed they may have to consider withdrawing maintenance from their rural road network.

......// some more text

2014-02-04 17:41:07.795 MYAPP[76113:70b] Website Text:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
NSString *webTextString =  [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innertext;"];
```

your capitalization is wrong. Should be `innerText`, not `innertext`.